# SES Boost Mail Speed

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

I am using SES and trying to send emails to almost 2000 people at one go. The code which I am using is written in JAVA using javamail library and it takes around 28 seconds to deliver 22 mails.

Is there any way I can boost the speed up by changing language or library or any alternate way. Here is my code for reference, I am already using threads:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class AmazonSESSample implements Runnable {
    private String to = "";
    public static Properties props = System.getProperties();
    public static Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    static final String FROM = "info@domain.com";
    static final String BODY = "This email was sent through the Amazon SES SMTP interface by using Java.";
    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";
    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "username";
    static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String HOST = "ses_host";
    static final int PORT = 000;

    public static Transport transport;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.sendMail();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setParameters(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    private void sendMail() throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        msg.setContent(BODY, "text/plain");
        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...");
            msg.saveChanges();
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.println("Email sent!" + date.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>(); // String list of emails
        transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++) {
            AmazonSESSample sendmail = new AmazonSESSample();
            sendmail.setParameters(emails.get(i).toString());
            Thread t = new Thread(sendmail);
            t.start();
        }
        // transport.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to find out which part of your code is slow. I expect that most of the time is spent talking with the mail server. If that is the case, changing language or library won't help.

Comment: @ThomasStets Most of the time is taken by `transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());` but I don't exactly know what to do. My SES quota is 22 mails per sec.

Comment: As I suggested in your other post, you need to do more detailed performance analysis.  Try enabling java.util.logging for the JavaMail loggers and examine the timestamps for the log messages to see which protocol messages is taking the most time.